# gpgtar missing from Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: server, 18.04, gnupg

Why do I keep getting "Command not found" when trying to use gpgtar on a fresh install of Ubuntu server 18.04.3? I checked and that command should be part of the gnupg or the gnupg-utils which are both installed and latest version. Thoughts?

*** UPDATE ***

```
username@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install gnupg-utils -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnupg-l10n gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnupg-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 127 kB of archives.
After this operation, 477 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gnupg-utils amd64 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [127 kB]
Fetched 127 kB in 0s (287 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package gnupg-utils.
(Reading database ... 66838 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnupg-utils (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up gnupg-utils (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...

username@hostname:~$ gpgtar
gpgtar: command not found
```

No change. Still does not recognize command.

Comment: May I then suggest you uninstall gnupg-utils and reinstall it; does the problem persist? Please click [edit] and add your findings to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The command `gpg-zip` seems to create a Tar file (despite its name):

```
$ gpg-zip --encrypt --output myarchive.tar.gpg --gpg-args --recipient=XXX myfile
$ gpg -d myarchive.tar.gpg > myarchive.tar
$ file myarchive.tar
test-decrypted: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

So you can use `gpg-zip` instead of the `gpgtar` command. `gpgtar` is not part of the `gnupg-utils` package in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    18.04
$ dpkg -L gnupg-utils
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gpg-zip
/usr/bin/gpgparsemail
/usr/bin/gpgsplit
/usr/bin/kbxutil
/usr/bin/lspgpot
/usr/bin/migrate-pubring-from-classic-gpg
/usr/bin/symcryptrun
/usr/bin/watchgnupg
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/addgnupghome
/usr/sbin/applygnupgdefaults
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gnupg-utils
/usr/share/doc/gnupg-utils/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnupg-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnupg-utils/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/gpg-zip.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gpgparsemail.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gpgsplit.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/kbxutil.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/lspgpot.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/migrate-pubring-from-classic-gpg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/symcryptrun.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/watchgnupg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/addgnupghome.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/applygnupgdefaults.8.gz
```